# Concise way to handle the Calendar object in Java

Tags: java, calendar

Some of the most used methods in the Calendar object return void and are not chainable, such as add(). Even more so, the class appears to be mutable where if you add, for example, a day to a Calendar object, the original Calendar object will be modified with the new date.

I have written this:

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// report.time() returns a Calendar instance
if(report.time().after(currentTime.getTime().add(Calendar.DATE, 1)) || currentTime.after( report.time().add(Calendar.MONTH, 5) )){
    validTime=false;
}
```

This does not compile because the add() methods being used in the parameters of after() return void and after() is expecting a Calendar instance, not void.

The only other solution I can think of is very ugly and bloated:

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
Calendar nextDay = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
nextDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 1))
Calendar nextMonths = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
nextMonths.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5))
if(report.time().after(nextDay) || currentTime.after(nextMonths )){
   validTime=false;
}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Did you check the Joda time library? If your projects allows you to use it, it has lot more easier APIs than inbuilt Calendar

Comment: After doing some research on Joda, apparently it is widely used and the Calendar class is shunned. I was using Calendar because it's discussed in the Oracle docs.

Comment: The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them, they really are that bad. Eventually even Sun/Oracle gave up on them, leading to the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8. The java.time package is inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) but is entirely re-architected. Joda-Time and java.time each have their pros and cons. I suggest learning about both and use each where they fit best. Just be careful with your `import` statements as some class names are common to both, (`LocalDate`}.

Comment: @JohnMerlino Your business rule in indecipherable to me, as it seems to be contradictory. You seem to be testing if the target date-time is before tomorrow and something else which I cannot determine. It may help if you define what *is* valid rather than invalid.

Comment: @BasilBourque initially I was planning to use java.time of Java 8 but there is no way to get UTC time with it. And that is when someone recommended using Calendar rather than LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your business logic regarding the valid range of date-times, as your code seems to be contradictory.

Here's some code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which may help you get going in the right direction. Let's say the target date-time is valid if it occurs between 3 days ago through tomorrow, for a 5-day span (3 days ago, today, tomorrow).

Usually the best practice in defining a span of time is the "half-open" approach. In this approach, the beginning of the span is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. So including tomorrow means we want every moment up to but not including the first moment of the day *after* tomorrow; so we add *two* days rather than *one* in code below. Search StackOverflow for more discussion and examples of "half-open".

The method `withTimeAtStartOfDay` adjusts to the first moment of the day. That moment is not always the time 00:00:00 because of Daylight Saving Time or other anomalies. In UTC the day will always start at that time, but as a habit you should avoid hard-coding that particular time (let Joda-Time do the work for you).

Not sure what you wanted, but it seems you want to define "tomorrow" by UTC. We do so here.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime momentAfterTomorrow = now.plusDays( 2 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay(); 
DateTime threeDaysAgo = now.minusDays( 3 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
Interval validInterval = new Interval( threeDaysAgo, momentAfterTomorrow );  // ( inclusive, exclusive )
```

Test if our target date-time occurs within that interval.

```
DateTime target = now.minusDays( 1 );  // Arbitrary choice.
boolean targetIsValid = validInterval.contains( target );  // True
```

Another test.

```
DateTime target2 = now.minusDays( 111 );  // Arbitrary choice.
boolean target2IsValid = validInterval.contains( target2 );  // False
```

By the way, Joda-Time offers three classes for defining various kinds of spans of time: Period, Interval, and Duration.

Comment: Joda Time is good. It seems I can achieve what I want like this: report.time().isAfter(currentTime.plusMonths(1)) || currentTime.isAfter( report.time().plusMonths(6)

Comment: By the way, do you know how to achieve the same using the new java 8 java.time classes?